# How to deploy Spring Cloud Gateway 2.1 on Jboss or Tomcat?

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, war, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to a deploy Spring Cloud Gateway but it is built on Spring Framework 5, Project Reactor.

Can I create a WAR file and deploy it on a traditional application server such as Jboss or Tomcat.

The Spring documentation in [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html) says it is possible.

> Spring WebFlux is supported on Tomcat, Jetty, Servlet 3.1+ containers

Note:
this is Spring Cloud Gateway project link
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Comment: Check out https://sandipchitale.medium.com/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-fn-6c8821395f22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, as Spring Cloud Gateway is itself a Spring Boot WebFlux application and this use case is only supported with embedded servers, [as mentioned in the Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file).