# How to deploy Spring Cloud Gateway application to local VM on windows?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway

I am writing multiple microservices and now I am setting up api-gateway using spring cloud gateway framework and netflix eureka discovery client. Since I am using spring boot gateway project I am able to run it as spring boot application withing eclipse and it routes smoothly to configured microservices.

Now I want to deploy api-gateway somewhere in server like tomcat. I am not able to understand How to do deployment of Sprig cloud Gateway project in local tomcat server ? Is it a right to deploy it on tomcat ?

It would be great if any one can help me to deploy spring cloud gateway.

I am attaching pom.xml file of spring cloud gateway project which has been derived from spring.io initializers.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.companyx.productx</groupId>
 <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>api-gateway</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you start the gateway as standalone app using java -jar yourapp.jar?

Comment: There is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438851/how-to-deploy-spring-cloud-gateway-2-1-on-jboss-or-tomcat

Comment: If I start gateway as standalone, by which port I can call url ?

Comment: Default is 8080. Maybe you should first read the Spring Boot documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Thank you @SimonMartinelli. Then spring api gateway cannot be deployed on any server instead of running standalone ?

Comment: Sure it can read the chapter about "WAR deployment"

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Spring Cloud Gateway doesn't work as war - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi_gateway-starter.html