# Spring Gateway deployment on external tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing a micro-service solution with spring boot. I have 3 micro services:

- authentication services (manages users, roles, permissions)
- project service (services used to do CRUD actions on Project entity)
- gateway (used as entry point of the solution, also used to validate token and route to services)

I want to deploy these on a tomcat server as war placed in the webapps (knowing that they have an embedded tomcat).
I am able to deploy the authentication and project services and they are reachable over the URI ** localhost:8080/authentication/* ** and ** /project/* **, but I'm unable to reach the gateway on ** localhost:8080/gateway/* **, it returns a 404

I am sure that the gateway is running cause it created the tables in the DB after deployment.

**Knowing that in eclipse it works fine (since i run each service on a port specified in the application.yml) i don't understand why when deploying the gateway on tomcat it is unreachable and always return a 404. I can see it in the tomcat manager as deployed.

Here is the pom.xml of the gateway :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gateway</name>
    <description>Gateway</description>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <springfox-swagger.version>3.0.0</springfox-swagger.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and here is my application.yml file :

```
spring:
   cloud:
     gateway:
       routes:
       - id: incident
         uri: http://localhost:8080/project
         predicates:
           - Path=/gateway/v1/project/**
         filters:
           - RewritePath=/gateway/(?<RID>.*), /$\{RID}
           - JwtFilter
           - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization
        
       - id: authentication
         uri: http://localhost:8080/auth
         predicates:
           - Path=/gateway/auth/**
         filters:
           - RewritePath=/gateway/(?<RID>.*), /$\{RID}

       - id: userManagement
         uri: http://localhost:8080/auth
         predicates:
           - Path=/gateway/v1/user/**,/gateway/v1/permission/**,/gateway/v1/role/**,/gateway/v1/role-permission/**,/gateway/v1/user-role/**
         filters:
           - RewritePath=/gateway/(?<RID>.*), /$\{RID}
           - JwtFilter
           - RemoveRequestHeader=Authorization
   datasource:
       url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain
       username: xxx
       password: xxx
   jpa:
       hibernate:
           ddl-auto: update
           id:
              new_generator_mappings=true
       properties:
           hibernate:
               temp:
                   use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
               dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
               physical_naming_strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
       show-sql: true

logging:
   level:
       org.springframework: TRACE
       org.hibernate.type: TRACE
       org.apache.tomcat: INFO
       org.apache.catalina: INFO
   pattern:
       console: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
       file: "%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n"
   file: 
       name: ./tomcat-logs/gateway
       path: ./tomcat-logs/gateway
```

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54438851/how-to-deploy-spring-cloud-gateway-2-1-on-jboss-or-tomcat

Comment: How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Gateway is itself a Spring Boot WebFlux application. It's support only embedded server. Please check spring documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-traditional-deployment

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway/)

> This project provides a libraries for building an API Gateway on top
> of Spring WebFlux or Spring WebMVC.

Then in build.gralde use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc'
```

Also, here a [handy article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) if needed.